# Помогите сориентироваться с архитектурой SpringMVC+андроид+web

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Немножко недопонимаю. Я хочу написать сервер на  Spring MVC  с которым будут работать браузер и андроид. С андроид все ясно(я сам андроид программист) я буду рестом слать и принимать JSON и все хорошо. А вот с браузером не понимаю. Я могу использовать JSP и строить веб страницу. И из этого вопросы
1. Если я использую  JSP то в нее тоже передавать  JSON? или для андроид и веба разные ссылки которые возвращают разные ответы? Просто веть я могу напрямую объекты передавать
2. Или сейчас популярно что-то другое, что отвечает за построение веб страниц, и если это что-то есть то что лучше всего работает с  spring? 
Цель написать сервер который будет отдавать данные удобно как андроиду так и вебу. И желательно   JSON потому что андроид в любом случае будет работать так.

Comment: По идее сервис (API) делается отдельно, сайт отдельно, на одном ядре, на одном сервере, но все же отдельно. Т.е. правильно сделать какой-то внутренний слой с бизнес-логикой, и далее разделить уже на уровне представления на web-сервис и web-страницы. Вы, конечно, можете с Вашей страницы через AJAX обращаться к API, но не уверен, что стоит с этого начинать =)

Answer (score 2):

ответ на вопрос трудно дать однозначно. Так как очень много способов. Предлогаю **REST API with Spring**

> REST (сокр. от англ. Representational State Transfer — «передача репрезентативного состояния») — метод взаимодействия компонентов распределённого приложения в сети Интернет, при котором вызов удаленной процедуры представляет собой обычный HTTP-запрос (обычно GET или POST; такой запрос называют REST-запрос), а необходимые данные передаются в качестве параметров запроса. Этот способ является альтернативой более сложным методам, таким как SOAP, CORBA и RPC.

имеется технология **REST API with Spring** для создание API части в сервере. Попробуйте его использовать.

Пример:

1. [Реализуем RESTful Web Service на java](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150034/)
2. [Build a REST API with Spring 4 and Java Config](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/25/building-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-3-1-and-java-based-configuration-part-2/)
3. [REST на примере Spring MVC](http://devcolibri.com/3732)

Comment: я итак написал что рест буду использовать. я вкурсе что это. вопрос был в другом - что для веб морды использовать?

Comment: а зачем API морда? ведь с ним будет работать робот. А для людей используйте другой сайт. я не видел что бы у API была морда